# Generics with Fluent and NHibernate

Tags: c#, generics, fluent-nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I am trying to create a messaging system between users and organizations - that is, a user can send and recieve messages from users or organizations.

So, to support this system, I started with an interface:

```
public interface IPassableObject<F, T, O>
    where F : DomainObject 
    where T : DomainObject
{
    Guid PassedItemId { get; set; }
    O Item { get; set; }
    F From { get; set; }
    T To { get; set; }
    DateTime Created { get; set; }
}
```

The idea is later I'd like to be able to pass more than just messages - like serialized objects.  So, we have a class with 3 Generic types.  The To, the From, and the object

Then I created my Message class

```
public class Message<T, F> : DomainObject, IPassableObject<T, F, string>
    where F : DomainObject
    where T : DomainObject
{

    public Message()
    {
        Created = DateTime.Now;
    }

    #region IPassableObject<T,F> Members

    public virtual Guid PassedItemId { get; set; }

    public virtual string Item { get; set; }

    public virtual T From { get; set; }

    public virtual F To { get; set; }

    public virtual DateTime Created { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

Then, I made my table to support my passed items:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PassedItems
(
    PassedItemId            uniqueidentifier        NOT NULL,
    FromId                  uniqueidentifier        NOT NULL,
    ToId                    uniqueidentifier        NOT NULL,
    SerializedObject        varchar(max)            NOT NULL,
    Created                 datetime                DEFAULT(GETEDATE()) NOT NULL,

    CONSTRAINT PK_PassedItems PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (PassedItemId)
)
```

The ID's for both my users and organizations are guids.  Now, I have my fluent mapping for The User - User messages.  My thought is that I will only have to create 4 mappings and not maintain 4 seperate classes for user-user, user-org, org-user, and org-org.  I was hoping that Nhibernate would take the guid in the table and automatically try and pull in the object based on the type specified.

```
public class UserToUserMessageMap : ClassMap<Message<UserProfile, UserProfile>>
{
    public UserToUserMessageMap()
    {
        WithTable("PassedItems");

        Id(x => x.PassedItemId, "PassedItemId").GeneratedBy.Guid();

        Map(x => x.Item, "SerializedObject");
        Map(x => x.Created);

        References(x => x.From, "FromId");
        References(x => x.To, "ToId");
    }
}
```

The issue I am seeing is that when I run my application, I get a runtime error:

> NHibernate.MappingException: An
>   association from the table PassedItems
>   does not specify the referenced entity

So, will this approach even work?  What am I doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: I tried changing the references by specifying a type.  Unfortunately, this didn't work either: References<UserProfile>(x => x.From, "FromId");

Comment: FYI - we are using FluentNHibernate version 0.1.0.363 and NHibernate version 2.0.1.4000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue.  To give a rough overview of what I did:

I had to dump the generics.

I have my interface, IPassable.

I have an abstract class that implements IPassable: PassableBase

I have my "dummy" class PassableItem that is inherited from PassableBase.  This class does nothing outside the defaults set in PassableBase.

Message is a class that also inherits from PassableBase.  Other passed objects will have to inherit from PassableBase.

My Fluent mapping uses PassableItem.

My repositories use PassableBase for input parameters and I create a new PassableItem or get a PassableItem from the store (depending on if it's created already or not), and then do my save/delete on the PassableItem object.

Answer (score 0):

So what does the mapping for 'From' & 'To' look like?

Because I think NH does not how to map these entities because you've not supplied the mapping info.

In general it sounds to me as thought you are re-inventing the wheel, have you looked at technology stacks like web services (SOAP & REST), message queueing, remoting (.Net). And specific implementations like WCF, ASMX (web services), nServiceBus, MassTransit, MSMQ to name just a few...

Ollie

Comment: From and To in this Instance are UserProfile object which are mapped and have been working for some time.  I think you misunderstand.  A "message" in this case is not a transport protocol.  It is an actual messaging system where users recieve messages in an inbox, and eventually I want to be able to expand the system to allow the users and organizations to sent more than just text.